# How to create custom text box in MVC4 with validation

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, textbox

I want to design Custom text box in MVC4.

Can anyone please suggest me the approach.

[image]

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: You can create custom HTML Helper to create TextBox with custom Attribute http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/787320/An-Absolute-Beginners-Tutorial-on-HTML-Helpers-and Or http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/views/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs

Comment: Sounds like you want some sort of masked edit control (for example [this one](http://help.syncfusion.com/ug/asp.net%20mvc/index.html#!Documents/addingmaskedittextboxtomvcapplication.htm))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this plugin [digitalBush Masking Plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/).

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $(".inputclass").mask("9999.99/9999.99");
        });
    </script>
```

HTML Source

```
<input type="text" class="inputclass" value="" />
```